# Protection of acces with Auto-Implemented Properties in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder

A simple example.
[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1854/51445300.jpg](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1854/51445300.jpg)

A have a class TDMReader which is a buldier of TDMFile objects and I am using Auto Implemented Properties f.e.

```
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Group[] Groups
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

What I want to do is to make setter accessible only for TDMReader methods.
In C++ i could have friends methods to access private variables, in Java I could make them in one packet and so access to fields. I have some ideas but with this auto-implemetation is a bit more complicated to do.
Any ideas with a nite solution?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic properties have no bearing on this - the same options are available for automatic properties and "manual" properties. You can restrict the access of the setter like this:

```
// Setter access only to this type and nested types
public string Name { get; private set; }
// Setter access within the assembly
public Group[] Groups { get; internal set; }
```

etc

... but you can't do it for a single class (unless that class is nested within the declaring type, in which case `private` would be fine). There's no namespace-restricted access in .NET or C#.

(It's not entirely clear which class the properties are declared in - if they're `TdmReader` properties, then just make them private. If they're `TdmFile` properties, you have the problem described above.)

Comment: "// Setter access only to this type and nested types
public string Name { get; private set; }"

AFIR, nested Class in C# has no reference to outer Class ( like in Java) it must be passed via contructor f.e.

with "manual: property i could co C-style trick 

set
{
 if(sth != null)
  { //some msg or ex}
 else
 { sth = value }
}

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public Group[] Groups
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

By adding the `private` keyword, the setters will only be accessible by code in the same class.  You can also add `internal` to make it accessible to code in the same project.

---

Note that exposing an array as a property is extremely poor design.
Instead, you should expose a `Collection<Group>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<Group>`, in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace.

Comment: array was just an exmaple. I am thinking about some Collection.
Didn't know about ReadOnlyCollection. Thx!